# Script tag won't close according to SublimeText2 even though I have proper syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to include a simple jquery plugin: menuFlip into my project.  When I try to call the plugin within the script tags it does not work on the webpage, and according to Sublime text 2 the script is never closed, as the closing script tag doesn't turn purple (stays yellow) and everything following stays yellow as well which is a sign that the script tag isn't closed..but the script tag is closed!  Here is my code. (This is just the footer.php where I am attempting to load my scripts.)

```
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.menuFlip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#flip_nav).menuFlip({
        li_height       : '20px', 
        flip_speed      : 150, 
        flipped_class   : 'flipped_item', 
        mouseover       : function() {}, 
        mouseout        : function() {}
        });
    });





</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The script tag that won't close is the one that I call document.ready in.
Now looking at the stackoverflow coloring, it appears SO considers those script tags to be closed at least according to their color coding..Thanks

Comment: missing `'` in `$('#flip_nav').m`

Comment: The problem is you have a hanging '   which means it is still part of a string, not an html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo in your code . You are missing `'` in your id selector

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#flip_nav').menuFlip({
        //----------^------ missing closing string selector
        li_height       : '20px', 
        flip_speed      : 150, 
        flipped_class   : 'flipped_item', 
        mouseover       : function() {}, 
        mouseout        : function() {}
        });
    });   
</script>
```

```js
!function(i){i.fn.menuFlip=function(e){var t=i.extend({li_height:"20px",flip_speed:150,flipped_class:"flipped_item",mouseover:function(){},mouseout:function(){}},e);this.find("li").css({overflow:"hidden",height:t.li_height}).hover(function(){var e="-"+t.li_height;i(this).find("a:first").animate({marginTop:e},t.flip_speed),"function"==typeof t.mouseover&&t.mouseover.call(this,this)},function(){i(this).find("a:first").animate({marginTop:"0px"},t.flip_speed),"function"==typeof t.mouseout&&t.mouseout.call(this,this)}).find("a").css({display:"block","line-height":t.li_height}).each(function(){var e=jQuery(this).data("flippedText")?jQuery(this).data("flippedText"):jQuery(this).text();i(this).clone().text(e).appendTo(i(this).parent()).addClass(t.flipped_class)})}}(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#flip_nav').menuFlip({
    //----------^------ missing closing string selector
    li_height: '20px',
    flip_speed: 150,
    flipped_class: 'flipped_item',
    mouseover: function() {},
    mouseout: function() {}
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="flip_nav">
  <li><a href="/home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/web">Web</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oops that corrects the syntax coloring on Sublime thanks.  The plug in still is not loading though?

Comment: Yes thank you I fixed that.  The plug in still isn't loading/working though?  I can't accept answer for another couple mins per SO. Any idea why it still wouldn't work?